# highchart not update point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to build a web chart which is show stock in candle stick. First, I load history json from url, then every second, I load current candle stick data and update last candle stick. But, in setInterval function, I can't load series data from chart. Always return null

```
$.getJSON('my_first_url', function(json) {
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: json

        }],
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {

                        $.getJSON('my_second_url', function(response) {

                            var data_time = jsonValue[0];
                            var data_open = jsonValue[1];
                            var data_high = jsonValue[3];
                            var data_low = jsonValue[4];
                            var data_close = jsonValue[5];

                            var length = series.data.length;
                            series.data[length - 1].update([data_time_open, data_open, data_high, data_low, data_close], true, true);

                        });
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: It might be because of the data grouping. When the data is grouped then series.data is null. Try to disable data grouping http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cspline%3E.dataGrouping.enabled Making ajax request in setInterval leads to race conditions, it is better to fetch the data using recursive setTimeout

Comment: I've remove datagroup in my code, but it's not working. However, when I use url in highchart demo. https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?a=e&filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=? It's work correctly. My Url return json. It's draw correctly on graph. but in setInterval not working. I dont understand. May it require JSONP?

Comment: OK, so it is the issue with how you deliver data - you need to set up your source/server correctly - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data